# What does the 'width' mean in scipy peak detection

Tags: python, scipy

Here's an example I'm trying:

```
import numpy
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
test = numpy.random.uniform(0.8, 1.0, 20)
plt.plot(test)
```

[image]

Then, I tried `find_peaks(test,width=3)`, and part of the output looks like

```
array([ 6, 12])
'left_bases': array([0, 8]),
'right_bases': array([ 8, 18]),
'widths': array([4.27554389, 4.16236512])
```

I'm wondering what those outputs mean, and how does the `widths` in output relevant to the `width` of my input? (If I change `width` to be 1 or 0, then more peaks are detected.) I've seen the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html#scipy.signal.peak_prominences), but still having trouble understanding their meanings.

Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, [the `width` parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks) means a peak will need to last for more than e.g. one sample to be registered as a peak.

This doesn't make much sense with your generated data, where it's essentially noise at your given sampling rate (as it were), but if you were to resample that 20-sample array to, say, 2000 samples, then you'd need a bigger `width` to properly capture the peaks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the greater value of `width` will allow me to filter out the noise and detect the peak in a larger sample, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that'd be it -- along with the `prominence` value.